# Android Espresso Ui Test verify label text of ActionPage

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-testing, android-espresso

I am trying to test the text of an ActionPage using Espresso. However, when I run the Ui Automation Viewer I can see that the ActionPage is being shown as a View instead of an ActionView and it does not have a TextView.

I have tried checking for the ActionLabel text like this but that does not work:

```
onView(withClassName(equalToIgnoringCase("android.support.wearable.view.ActionLabel"))).check(matches(withText("MyText")));
```

I have an id for my ActionPage so I can find it with `onView(withId(R.id.actionPage))` but I dont know how to access its children to get at ActionLabel text. I tried writing a custom matcher but this also does not work:

```
onView(withId(R.id.actionPage)).check(matches(withChildText("MyText")));

static Matcher<View> withChildText(final String string) {
        return new BoundedMatcher<View, View>(View.class) {
            @Override
            public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
                ViewGroup viewGroup = ((ViewGroup) view);
                //return (((TextView) actionLabel).getText()).equals(string);
                for(int i = 0; i < view.getChildCount(); i++){
                    View child = view.getChildAt(i);
                    if (child instanceof TextView) {
                        return ((TextView) child).getText().toString().equals(string);
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("with child text: " + string);
            }
        };
    }
```

Could someone please help me out, the ActionLabel does not seem to have an id by itself and its not a TextView...how can I check the text inside of it?

```
+------>FrameLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=320, height=320, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+------->ActionPage{id=2131689620, res-name=actionPage, visibility=VISIBLE, width=320, height=320, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+-------->ActionLabel{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=285, height=111, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=17.0, y=209.0}
|
+-------->CircularButton{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=144, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=88.0, y=65.0}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to add  programmatically content description or id to at least one of this layouts? It would be much easier to catch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `withParent` with `allOf`:

```
onView(
    allOf(
      withParent(withId(R.id.actionPage)),
      isAssignableFrom(ActionLabel.class)))
  .check(matches(withActionLabel(is("MyText"))));
```

Unfortunately `ActionLabel` does not expose its text via `getText()`, so instead of the standard `withText()` matcher, you have to write a custom one using reflection:

```
private static Matcher<Object> withActionLabel(
    final Matcher<CharSequence> textMatcher) {
  return new BoundedMatcher<Object, ActionLabel>(ActionLabel.class) {
    @Override public boolean matchesSafely(ActionLabel label) {
      try {
        java.lang.reflect.Field f = label.getClass().getDeclaredField("mText");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        CharSequence text = (CharSequence) f.get(label);
        return textMatcher.matches(text);
      } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        return false;
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    @Override public void describeTo(Description description) {
      description.appendText("with action label: ");
      textMatcher.describeTo(description);
    }
  };
}
```

More info: http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/05/espresso-match-toolbar-title.html

Please file a bug to request Google to add a public method `ActionLabel.getText()` so you can test it without reflection.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is `ActionLabel` is not assignable to `TextView` and `ActionLabel` does not have a public `getText()` method.

Comment: Is `ActionLabel` your custom view? If so, you can add a `getText()` method and write a custom matcher using that. See the blog link for a sample custom matcher.

Comment: Its not, its an android class. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/ActionPage.html

Comment: Try simply `onView(
      withParent(withId(R.id.actionPage)))
  .check(matches(withText("MyText")));`

Comment: I have edited the answer to include a custom matcher to verify the `ActionLabel` using reflection.